# Apache Rewrite to File System Or Proxy

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to create an Apache `mod_rewrite` rule to do **two things**:

1. Serve the contents of a file system directory when `/file-system-target` is requested and
2. Proxy whenever `/file-system-target` is not requested.

E.g.:

```
RewriteRule ^/file-system-target /path/to/file/system/target [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8080 [P]
```

However when watching the output of `RewriteLog`, the **latter rule is always matched and the former is never matched**. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the statement **"latter rule is always matched & the former is never matched"** may not have been true; I had a confusing httpd.conf in which rewrite logging was enabled in more than one place.

In any event, the first rule was definitely incomplete. It should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/file-system-target(.+)$ /path/to/file/system/target/$1 [L]
```

I also added an additional rule to handle the (lack of) trailing slash:

```
RewriteRule ^/file-system-target$ /path/to/file/system/target/$1 [L]
```

So I ended up with:

```
RewriteRule ^/file-system-target$ /path/to/file/system/target/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/file-system-target(.+)$ /path/to/file/system/target/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8080 [P]
```

I'm going to assume there are more elegant ways to implement this feature, but I'm satisfied enough with the above configuration to call this task "done".